# Opening JFrame from another package in the main window

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have 2 packages and they each contain a seperate MyFrame class that extends JFrame. I have a third package with a MyFrame Class thet extend JFrame.

I want to display the JFrames from the other packages in my "main" package JFrame when i press the corresponding button.

How would I do That?

this is what i have right now:
public class MyFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

```
private JButton voorraadbeheer, klantenbinding, werkplaats, facturatie,
        parkeergarage;
private JPanel mainMenu;
private JDPanel mainWindow;

public MyFrame() {
    Dimension button = new Dimension(100, 100);

    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    voorraadbeheer = new JButton("Voorraadbeheer");
    klantenbinding = new JButton("klantenbinding");
    werkplaats = new JButton("Werkplaats");
    facturatie = new JButton("Facturatie");
    parkeergarage = new JButton("Parkeergarage");

    voorraadbeheer.setPreferredSize(button);
    klantenbinding.setPreferredSize(button);
    werkplaats.setPreferredSize(button);
    facturatie.setPreferredSize(button);
    parkeergarage.setPreferredSize(button);

    voorraadbeheer.addActionListener(this);
    klantenbinding.addActionListener(this);
    werkplaats.addActionListener(this);
    facturatie.addActionListener(this);
    parkeergarage.addActionListener(this);

    mainMenu = new JPanel();
    mainMenu.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(120, 600));
    mainMenu.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

    mainMenu.add(voorraadbeheer);
    mainMenu.add(klantenbinding);
    mainMenu.add(werkplaats);
    mainMenu.add(facturatie);
    mainMenu.add(parkeergarage);

    add(mainMenu, BorderLayout.EAST);

    mainWindow = new JPanel();
    mainWindow.setVisible(true);
    add(mainWindow);

    setSize(1024, 600);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object eventSource = e.getSource();

    if (eventSource == klantenbinding) {
        try {
            klantenbinding.MyFrame klantenbindingFrame = new klantenbinding.MyFrame();
            mainWindow.add(klantenbindingFrame);
        } catch (ParseException exc) {
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Make classes public to access it from anywhere.

Comment: I second @wumpz's question, and add: what happens when you try to do this? Are you seeing any error messages? Does the code not compile? Are the packages in the same project? The more information that you can tell us about your problem, the better we can understand it and help you.

Comment: @wumpz I'v tried to add it to a JPanel but that didn't work, then i googled but i couldnt find anything that made sense

Comment: Show some real source code.

Comment: `"that didn't work"` tells us little that we can use to help you. How doesn't it work? Do you get compiler errors? Exceptions during program run? And this `" then i googled but i couldnt find anything that made sense"` helps even less. Come on please give us some help here.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels it said I couldnt add a window to a container, which makes sense but after that I haven't tried anything cause I couldn't figure out a way to do it.

Comment: You're still not showing the code that failed. Please show that to us. It's always better to give a little more information to us than too little information. Otherwise we can get into this game of trying to extract dribs and drabs of information incrementally from you, which is nothing but a lot of frustration for both of us.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I've added it. I'm fairly new here so still learning. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you simply try to display the other window, and not add it to your current GUI?

```
if (eventSource == klantenbinding) {
    try {
        klantenbinding.MyFrame klantenbindingFrame = new klantenbinding.MyFrame();
        // mainWindow.add(klantenbindingFrame);
        klantenbindingFrame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  // never ignore exceptions
    }
}
```

Having said this, I think that you're making a common beginner's Swing mistake of making classes that are geared towards making JFrame. This makes for very inflexible code, as you're finding out. Better to gear your code towards making JPanels, as these ***can*** be placed in other JFrames, in other JPanels, in JApplets, in JDialogs, swapped with CardLayouts, etc...

---

**Edit**
A kludge that might work for you is to get the contentPane of the other JFrame and insert that:

```
if (eventSource == klantenbinding) {
    try {
        klantenbinding.MyFrame klantenbindingFrame = new klantenbinding.MyFrame();
        Component contentPane = klantenbindingFrame.getContentPane();
        mainWindow.add(contentPane);
        mainWindow.revalidate();
        mainWindow.repaint();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();  // never ignore exceptions
    }
}
```

Comment: that works, but i want to add it to my current GUI. youre right about the beginner. this is for a School Project. thanks for the tip

Comment: @LiamdeHaas: As an aside, your original question looks to have nothing to do with classes being in different packages. Please try to make your questions more complete by giving us all the necessary useful information from the start including pertinent code, code attempts, and any and all error messages. And avoid making assumptions about what's wrong until you know for sure what's wrong. This will help avoid mutual frustration and will get you better and quicker answers.

Comment: I used your suggestion and it displays the content, but it still opens the frame

Comment: @LiamdeHaas: that's the fault of your `klantenbinding.MyFrame` class. Its constructor likely has code that opens an new JFrame. You will have to fix your code. Again, you are ***far*** better off to have your classes create JPanels and ***not*** JFrames. Believe me that this will greatly increase the flexibility of your GUI's.

Comment: Could it work if i remove this part from my klantenbinding.MyFrame class?  `setSize(900, 600);
  setVisible(true);
  setResizable(false);
  setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`

Comment: Will keep the JPanel over JFrame for flexibility in mind for the next project

Comment: @LiamdeHaas: try it and see.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Make sure, that the package of the second frame is imported and the class is public.

```
package test;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import test2.Frame1;

public class DemoFrame {

private JFrame frame;
private JButton btn;

public DemoFrame() {
    frame = new JFrame("Demo Frame");
    frame.setSize(300, 300);
    btn = new JButton("Click for second frame");
    btn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //create second frame
            Frame1 frame1 = new Frame1();
        }

    });
    frame.add(btn);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            new DemoFrame();
        }
    });
}

}
```

Second Frame:

```
public class Frame1 extends JFrame{

public Frame1() {
    this.setTitle("Frame1");
    this.setSize(300,300);
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to import the package of your other frames

```
import main.myframespackage.*;
```

This is necessary to make this class "visible" to your actual class. You should look over javas package concept e.g. here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/usepkgs.html. Maybe it is useful to study as well the visibility concepts of java methods and classes, e.g. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html.

Lets the name of one of your frames be `TestFrame2`. Then you could display it like so:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object eventSource = e.getSource();
    if (eventSource == klantenbinding) {
        TestFrame2 tframe2 = new TestFrame2();
        tframe2.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```